# Can I split the activity flow in an activity diagram using the activity final node?

Tags: android-activity, uml, diagram, diagramming

I have a use case diagram and the the following is a piece of it, the piece needed to depict what I want to do:

[image]

And I've drawn the activity diagrams of **Turn ON with KNOB** and **Turn OFF with KNOB** the following way:

[image]

[image]

But I'm not sure about the **Final Node** in the decision branches of both diagrams. What I want to do is to keep separate diagrams for the Turn ON with KNOB and Turn Off with KNOB use case diagrams but I'm not sure if the placement of a *Final Node* in the decision is the correct way to represent that, for instance, the *flow* in the activity diagram for the *Turn ON with KNOB* ends if at the decision branch results that the system is already ON, this because if the system is already ON then the activity diagram that correspond is the *Turn OFF with KNOB* activity diagram.

But It seems quite confusing because **How Do I know which activity diagram to choose if both are the same until the decision branch is reached?** What I mean is that, is it correct from a UML compliant perspective to, for instance, start following the flow of the **Turn ON with KNOB** activity diagram and then reach the decision branch and determine that the system is already ON and just "jump" to the activity diagram correspondign to the **Turn OFF with KNOB** use case and continue following the flow in the latter diagram from the decision branch? Or should I stick strictly to the scenario that the **System is already OFF** and pick the **Turn ON with KNOW** activity diagram?

Now, this leads me to another question; **Can I represent more than one use case per activity diagram?**

Answer (score 0):

The UML specification says that *an activity may have more than one activity final node. The first one reached stops all flows in the activity.* (Thus, in your example, the control flow stops either because the light was already on/off, or after being turned in that state). Alternatively, you may make both edges target the same final node*, it is equivalent since the only purpose of the final node is terminating the activity.

In my opinion, each use case should be separate from the others (though an activity may contain nested activities, which would model lower level behaviors).

(*Note that it is not "final state" but "final node", since it is in an activity diagram. State machines have final states.) Also, you are not "splitting" the activity flow (as in a fork node), since the decision node chooses exactly one outgoing edge.